# Aborted Ubuntu installation on Dual-boot system

Tags: dual-boot, system-installation, windows, data-recovery

I am facing a problem with my laptop:

Natively, I was using windows 8 as OS on my laptop, then wanted to change the OS to Ubuntu. During the Ubuntu installing process, I wrongly selected the drive where Windows was installed, so in that drive both the OSs were installed. However, I stopped the Ubuntu installation process, and when I restarted my laptop it shows an error like `missing operating system`.

I then wanted to re install Windows 8, however the disk partition drives are not showing.  In the case of using the Ubuntu installation medium with "try ubuntu" live version, my `D:` and `E:` drives are showing.

How to proceed? My data is very important to me and must be recovered.

Comment: first step is saving your data then: 1) get an external drive - depending on the amount of data you can use a USB flash drive or a proper one 2) boot using the live cd 3) mount the windows partitions 4) copy your data. Then you can start with repairing.

Comment: sir, i also do the same thing, but in the booting time i can't get the parititioned drives

Comment: You will have to mount them: list your drives and partitions: `ls /dev/sd*`.  Any partition will be called `sdAX` where `A=a,b,c..` and `X=1,2,3..` for each partition (not the drives `sdA`!) try: `mkdir /mnt/sdAX/` to create a mount point, then `mount /dev/sdAX /mnt/sdAX` if this succeeds, you can search the drive and copy data to your USB drive. NOTE: also the USB drive will show as one of `sdA`.

Comment: my system is not working.where do i have to follow the steps u suggested earlier? using a ubuntu cd or what

Comment: Did you use the Ubuntu installation medium and `Try Ubunutu` for this?

Answer (score 0):

First, Use the Ubuntu Installation Medium and `Try Ubuntu`. Open `gParted` and check the names of the partition. Try to mount the partition and copy the data to a safe location like an external hard drive as stated above. Do not copy data into the hard drive as it may overwrite the previous data.

Next try `TestDisk` to recover the partition tables. Use this [link](http://www.geekyprojects.com/storage/how-to-repair-a-damaged-partition-table-or-mbr/).

If you are unable to recover the data or the partition tables, I suggest you use [EaseUS Data Recovery](http://www.easeus.com/data-recovery-wizard-winpe/winpe-for-data-recovery.htm) and create a bootable pendrive to recover your data. Make sure you recover data to another hard drive.

After that you may proceed with the installation of Windows 8 followed by Ubuntu installation.